# How am I supposed to gather the data from DB using 2 threads?

Tags: java, database

I have a DB with like 1600+ records, it looks slow to read all the records so I got an idea to use 2 threads to get the data. I have the following functions but it does not feel like it is faster...

```
private ArrayList<Worker> getWorkersOnMultipleThread() throws InterruptedException {
    ArrayList<Worker> totalWorkers = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Worker> totalWorkers2 = new ArrayList<>();
    int total = db.getNumberOfWorkers();
    int firstHalf, secondHalf;
    firstHalf = total / 2;
    if (total % 2 == 1) {
        secondHalf = total / 2 + 1;
    } else {
        secondHalf = total / 2;
    }

    Thread t1 = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ArrayList<Worker> w1 = db.getHalfOfTheWorkers(firstHalf, true);
            totalWorkers.addAll(w1);
        }
    };

    Thread t2 = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ArrayList<Worker> w2 = db.getHalfOfTheWorkers(secondHalf, false);
            totalWorkers2.addAll(w2);
        }
    };

    t1.start();
    t1.join();
    t2.start();
    t2.join();

    totalWorkers.addAll(totalWorkers2);

    return totalWorkers;
}

@Override
public ArrayList<Worker> getHalfOfTheWorkers(int limit, Boolean firstHalf) {
    String sql;
    ArrayList<Worker> workers = new ArrayList<>();
    if (firstHalf) {
        sql = "SELECT * FROM NAMES ORDER BY ID FETCH NEXT " + limit + " ROWS ONLY";
    } else {
        sql = "SELECT * FROM NAMES ORDER BY ID OFFSET " + limit + " ROWS";
    }
    try {
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String name = rs.getString("name");
            int id = rs.getInt("id");
            workers.add(new Worker(id, name));
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
    return workers;
}
```

My idea was to get first 50% of the records on the first thread, and the second 50% on the second thread and hopefully half the time it needs to get all records. It does not seem to work (I mean it does not give error and stuff and it has the same speed...)

Main:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    ArrayList<Worker> totalWorkers = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        totalWorkers = getWorkersOnMultipleThread();
        System.out.println(totalWorkers.size());
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Controller.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are starting the threads sequentially, that is when `t1` is started main is in waiting state as you used `t1.join()`. The `t2` thread is not started until `t1` thread has finished executing.

```
t1.start();
t1.join(); //main waiting
t2.start();
t2.join();
```

So you would be needing to change the order:

```
t1.start();
t2.start();
t1.join(); //main waiting
t2.join();
```

This way both the threads `t1` and `t2` would be started in parallel and you would instruct main to wait until both `t1` and `t2` has finished executing.

Ideally `statement` object should not be shared between the threads. You should be getting a `Connection` object per thread from a thread pool.

Since you are using Apache derby, the developer's guide [discourages the sharing of connection](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.5/devguide/cdevconcepts89498.html).

> - Avoid sharing Statements (and their ResultSets) among threads. Each    time a thread executes a Statement, it should process the results before relinquishing the Connection.
> - Each time a thread accesses the Connection, it should consistently    commit or not, depending on application protocol.
> - Have one thread be the "managing" database Connection thread that    should handle the higher-level tasks, such as establishing the
>     Connection, committing, rolling back, changing Connection properties
>     such as auto-commit, closing the Connection, shutting down the
>     database (in an embedded environment), and so on.
> - Close ResultSets and Statements that are no longer needed in order to    release resources.

Comment: if I do this, it does not get back any data, I edit the main post and copy-paste there the main method. The "totalWorkers.size()" is 12 like this.

Comment: If it is start-join-start-join, the result is 1604. At start-start-join-join it is 12...

Comment: What should be the expected output? 1604?

Comment: Yeah. I got 1604 records.

Comment: See my updated answer, you should be using a connection pool and not sharing the same connection/statement across multiple threads. I have assumed you are using Oracle driver.

Comment: I'm using apache derby. I will read that article. Also do you have any suggestion (keywords) how to speed up the record gathering from database? Not like my program needs something like it, I am just curious larger system how do it...

Answer (score 0):

Your bottleneck isn't in the processing of 1600 rows-- that's simply too few records to worry about, small records at that.  Your problem is more likely something like the time it takes to warm up a new connection for the request (in which case, using 2 cold connections in parallel will not save you any time).

Look at a connection pooling service like C3P0, DBCP or HikariCP and just do a single fetch.